Remove extra vertical space introduced before bibliography sections
I have a document similar to the MWE below. I use LuaLaTeX (and biber) to build it. I am defining my bib file in the same document for convenience here.
What I find is that an extra undesired vertical space is added before the \printbibsection calls for each bibliography entry type.
Using \usepackage{parskip} seems to correct the problem in part... but that messes up with other parts of my real document.
How can I get rid of these undesired vertical spaces without changing the format of the rest of the document? I want to maintain the separation between paragraphs, article entries, etc.
This is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus \smallskipamount minus \smallskipamount}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Bibliography

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose, date=year, maxbibnames=10, minbibnames=10, doi=false, isbn=false, url=true]{biblatex}%

\setlength{\bibhang}{8pt} %default=10pt

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}

%article

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    {\itshape \printfield{title}}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \itshape%
        \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
        \setunit{\space}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield{url}%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
}

%thesis

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
    {\itshape \printfield{title}}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    \printnames{author}%
    \par\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}%
    \newblock%
    {%
        \small \itshape%
        \printfield{type}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        \usebibmacro{location+date}%
        \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
        %\printfield{pages}%
        \newunit%
        \printfield{url}%
    }
    \par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{%
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type={#1}, heading=none]
    \end{refsection}
}

%bib file

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Kared2021,
    abstract = {Characterization of the T cell response...},
    author = {Hassen Kared and Andrew D Redd and Evan M Bloch and Tania S Bonny and Hermi Sumatoh and Faris Kairi and Daniel Carbajo and Brian Abel and Evan W Newell and Maria P Bettinotti and Sarah E Benner and Eshan U Patel and Kirsten Littlefield and Oliver Laeyendecker and Shmuel Shoham and David Sullivan and Arturo Casadevall and Andrew Pekosz and Alessandra Nardin and Michael Fehlings and Aaron Ar Tobian and Thomas C Quinn},
    doi = {10.1172/JCI145476},
    issn = {1558-8238},
    issue = {5},
    journal = {The Journal of Clinical Investigation},
    month = {3},
    pmid = {33427749},
    title = {SARS-CoV-2-specific CD8+ T cell responses in convalescent COVID-19 individuals.},
    volume = {131},
    url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33427749},
    year = {2021},
}
@article{Kared2020,
    abstract = {Characterization of the T cell response...},
    author = {Hassen Kared and Andrew D Redd and Evan M Bloch and Tania S Bonny and Hermi Sumatoh and Faris Kairi and Daniel Carbajo and Brian Abel and Evan W Newell and Maria P Bettinotti and Sarah E Benner and Eshan U Patel and Kirsten Littlefield and Oliver Laeyendecker and Shmuel Shoham and David Sullivan and Arturo Casadevall and Andrew Pekosz and Alessandra Nardin and Michael Fehlings and Aaron Ar Tobian and Thomas C Quinn},
    doi = {10.1101/2020.10.08.330688},
    issn = {2692-8205},
    journal = {bioRxiv: The Preprint Server for Biology},
    month = {10},
    pmid = {33052343},
    title = {CD8+ T cell responses in convalescent COVID-19 individuals target epitopes from the entire SARS-CoV-2 proteome and show kinetics of early differentiation.},
    url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33052343},
    year = {2020},
}
@thesis{Carbajo2012b,
    abstract = {The function of a protein...},
    author = {Daniel Carbajo},
    location = {Sapienza University of Rome},
    pages = {1-103},
    title = {Resource for benchmarking the usefulness of protein structure models.},
    type = {PhD Thesis},
    url = {https://iris.uniroma1.it/handle/11573/917016},
    year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%Document

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \printbibsection{article}
    \printbibsection{thesis}
\end{document}

Which produces this:

I highlighted in red the spaces that I want to get rid of.

Space #1 should be identical to the space between the 2 paragraphs (indicated with a blue cross).
Space #2 should be identical to the space between article entries (indicated with a green cross).
(Ideally the blue cross and green cross spaces should be identical.)

What would be the best way to do so without affecting the rest of the document?
I would like to avoid using \usepackage{parskip} and also, if possible, introducing negative \vspace indiscriminately... What is the elegant way to get rid of those spaces?
Thanks!

Any help here anyone?

add \vskip-2.35ex after \printbibsection{article}. i.e. You should remove space after section.

Any solution without the use of negative vertical space?
